# AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'requests'

Tags: python, django

I have the following models:

```
class App(models.Model):
    name                    = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    ...    

class Request(models.Model):
    ...
    app        = models.ForeignKey(App)
    ...
```

When trying the following:

```
a = App.objects.all().prefetch_related('request_set')

for r in a.requests:
    print r
```

It's giving:

```
AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'requests'
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong attribute to access the requests on your App - you need to use `a.request_set` (or set `related_name` in your `ForeignKey` definition to be 'requests').

Comment: My bad - try `for app in a: print app.requests` - `a` is a `QuerySet`, not an App object.

Comment: This is giving: AttributeError: 'App' object has no attribute 'requests'

Comment: OK, it was for r in app.request_set.all(): :)